# uncheck all checkboxes except the one with a class?

Tags: jquery

hi i try to check/uncheck all checkboxes that don't got a class to them. This is the code I got but it check the class boxes to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repReceivers_ctl00_chxAll').click(
         function() {
        if (!$("input[type='checkbox']").hasClass("testclass")) {
             $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repReceivers_ctl00_chxAll').is(':checked'));
         }});
    });
```

any ideas where I go wrong?

**EDIT**
This suck but asp.net add a span around the checkbox input when given a cssclass, so the checkbox itself dont get the class. I tried to do like you say but like .not(thecheckboxid) but no luck.

**EDIT CODE**

```
<span class="testclass"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chxMale" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chxMale" /></span>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for one checkbox (including said span)?

Comment: @Dejan - Answer below is updated for your markup :)

Comment: Wont work. It don't uncheck any checkbox now

Comment: @Dejan - Do you other ones have *no* class, as in no wrapping span?

Comment: No they don't got the span. the span is only given if the input got class to it. I could do a easy way out and attach span to the rest but if there is a way with pure jquery i rather do that

Comment: @Dejan - Updated again for no spans at all, a bit confusing to look at bit give it a try :)  This checks if the parent doesn't have the class, regardless of what the parent is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your code a bit, like this (**updated for updated question**):

```
$(function() {
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repReceivers_ctl00_chxAll').click(function() {
    $(":not(.testclass) > input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Currently you're checking if the **first** matched checkbox has the class, you want to filter out *all* those without the class from the batch you're setting the `checked` property on.  There are a few methods to do this, but [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) are the easiest here.  The other change above is that since you're inside an event handler for the `_chxAll` checkbox, you can use `this` instead of repeating the ID, it's shorter and faster :)  With this you can use the [`.checked`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) DOM property as well.

Comment: Wow... You're seriously choosing `$(this).is(':checked')` over `this.checked`...?

Comment: @J-P - Was refining the answer, had trouble finding the `.checked` property documentation...I don't use something unless I can provide a link to it in case there are any questions :)

Answer (score 3):

I added a few much-needed performance improvements.

```
var inputs = $('input:checkbox').not('.testclass');

$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repReceivers_ctl00_chxAll').click(
    function() {
        inputs.attr('checked', this.checked);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:checkbox').not('.testclass').attr('checked', $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_repReceivers_ctl00_chxAll').is(':checked'));
```